# Resize UIView using autolayout with fix bottom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

When keyboard appears I want to resize `view1` using `Autolayout`, I have also `view2` at the bottom of the screen like this:

[image]

`layoutConstraint` between `view1` & `view2` is

[image]

I created the `IBOutlet` and did this

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)n {

    NSDictionary *info  = n.userInfo;
    NSValue      *value = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect rawFrame      = [value CGRectValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:rawFrame fromView:nil];

    _blc.constant = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame)-35;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}


-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)n {
    _blc.constant = 0.0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

`view2` is of `height 35` so when keyboard appear and disappear there is a visible gap under `view1` like this

[image]

I intentionally gave the base `UIView` an aqua colour to tell about the gap.

How can I cover this gap when resizing `view1`?

Comment: What happens when you say _blc.constant = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame);?

Comment: same problem gap is still visible when keyboard appear and disappear.

Answer (score 0):

So if I have got it right, what you want to do is to resize your View1 with the keyboard, and leave View2 below of it?
If that's it and your view is something like this:

```
--------------
View1
View2
--------------
```

You should have a vertical space constraint from View1.bottom >= View2.top with 0 constant; and another vertical space constraint from View1.bottom to Superview.bottom = (whatever interface builder suggests you). The constraint you want to IBOutlet is the last one.

When the keyboard appears/dissapears, you update the constant of it as you did before. That should do it.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: nope its not working, same problem gap is still visible when keyboard appear and disappear.

Comment: How are you updating the constraint?

Comment: as you said the last one which is between view1 & superview bottom layout guide. When set in Xcode its constant is 35.0 and when keyboardWillAppear I am set the constant same as keyboard height. But still same issue the gap is still visible. Its easily visible in simulator with slow animation on.

Comment: where does the view2 ends up? below the keyboard?

Comment: view2 is at the end of screen and its height is 30.0 and above its view1 with vertical space of 0 constant.

Comment: Try pinning your View1.bottom to the Superview.bottom and not to the bottomLayoutGuide.